# Stop generic database questions from getting [mysql] as a suggested tag

Tags: feature-request, suggested-tags

Many of the questions about Microsoft Access come from relatively new users of databases and of Stack Overflow. I have noticed that quite a few of them are tagged as [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) even though MySQL is not actually involved.

At first I thought the askers were arbitrarily choosing [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) because they didn't know the difference ("A database is a database, right?"), but when I tried creating my own copy of a recent Access question I found that SO is actually *suggesting* the 'mysql' tag:

[image]

It would be nice if SO stopped offering [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) as a default(?) tag suggestion for generic database questions. It must be confusing to the database newbies and annoying to the followers of the 'mysql' tag.

Comment: This may explain why lately I've seen quite a lot of questions tagged with [tag:mysql] AND [tag:sql-server]

Comment: "In fact I am having a problem with my sql.  Thanks for the suggestion, SO."

Comment: "I am aslo having problems with mytable and myform. Better add those tags too."

Comment: @BilltheLizard Ooooh, can I create new tags for [tag:mytable] and [tag:myform]? :)

Comment: I started skipping questions tagged `mysql` for the very same issue expressed by OP.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Adding more of those tags isn't a good idea as it will increase confusion among newcomers. I suggest to replace all those tags by [tag:mydatabase] instead. This tag would also be a valid default for all database related questions.

Comment: ...the suggestions are made by a computer, right?

Comment: Another funny thing are the bots who remove more generic tags in favor of more specific http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20765668/revisions - so it's an endless cycle of bots getting rep and human reviwers wasting their time.

Comment: I think database is better than mydatabase , database tag exists and this what should be suggested

Comment: I wonder if anyone has ever looked at this. It is (still) a rather annoying effect.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, what we can do is to actively remove the [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) from obvious no-MySQL questions. That will in turn reduce the [similar-to-Bayesian calculations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212310/213575) probability that the tag can be suggested. It's a daunty (aka boring) task (aka chore), but is the best we have right now (other than a tag warning... but who read those?).

Comment: The linked answer says *"It has been trained on older questions"*, which basically seems to imply it will need an additional (possibly manually-triggered) training pass before the predictions will be updated.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski [I'm not sure is like that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319540/tags-not-older-than-6-months-should-not-be-suggested#comment325761_319547)