# Tags not older than 6 months should not be suggested

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, suggested-tags

While tag suggestion is helpful overall, there's a characteristic that come about as annoying: it has the knack of suggesting bad tags immediately they get created. This thwarts any attempt to contain the damage, and in some cases these bad tags seems to *"breed like rabbits"*. Can tags no older than 6 months be exempted from the suggested tags?

Comment: You talking about the keyword-based tag suggestions? Or auto complete. Because if you mean the former, I'd like to see a concrete example.

Comment: @Shog9 the ones that appear when you finish to write your question and move the cursor to the tag section. [These](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QElkw.png)

Comment: This sounds like a great way to end up with [tag:amazework], [tag:amazework.js], [tag:amazework-framework] and maybe even [tag:javascript-amazework] when someone releases their new Amazework framework.  I know what you're thinking but I'm not sure your suggestion would be an improvement.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom well, what's preventing people from organically tag their questions with those tags?

Comment: @Braiam They type _amazew_, see the tag (whichever one) that already exists, and choose that one.  Yes, an obstinate user can still create a duplicate tag, but your proposal would make it more likely that well-meaning users will do so accidentally.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom no. They will not. Since the tag suggestion is strongly biased towards presenting tag suggestion to <200 rep users.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a list of all tags suggested during the past 30 days (+ number of times suggested):

```
tag                       suggested 
------------------------- --------- 
javascript                45367     
android                   36118     
jquery                    34225     
java                      31627     
php                       29777     
html                      23557     
css                       23000     
python                    21557     
c#                        21199     
mysql                     20289     
c++                       19178     
ios                       15167     
r                         9220      
angularjs                 8652      
c                         8288      
sql-server                6918      
ruby-on-rails             6650      
node.js                   6353      
json                      6014      
arrays                    5753      
asp.net                   5302      
excel                     4820      
objective-c               4661      
regex                     4210      
twitter-bootstrap         4152      
spring                    4144      
xml                       4050      
django                    3874      
git                       3698      
ruby                      3508      
linux                     3422      
ajax                      3205      
eclipse                   3200      
vba                       3118      
wordpress                 3022      
asp.net-mvc               2611      
multithreading            2565      
iphone                    2397      
facebook                  2357      
mongodb                   2342      
wpf                       2336      
maven                     2307      
excel-vba                 2269      
apache                    2183      
google-maps               2059      
bash                      2044      
matlab                    2027      
spring-mvc                1917      
csv                       1805      
.htaccess                 1794      
hibernate                 1728      
visual-studio-2012        1709      
amazon-web-services       1656      
email                     1619      
algorithm                 1617      
forms                     1585      
sockets                   1510      
entity-framework          1499      
date                      1490      
azure                     1471      
symfony2                  1437      
vb.net                    1431      
css3                      1406      
oracle                    1400      
postgresql                1387      
android-fragments         1357      
osx                       1315      
asp.net-mvc-4             1314      
numpy                     1278      
.net                      1235      
string                    1223      
c++11                     1197      
ssl                       1185      
linq                      1168      
cordova                   1158      
opencv                    1157      
ruby-on-rails-3           1153      
web-services              1149      
hadoop                    1134      
batch-file                1131      
html5                     1130      
swing                     1130      
uitableview               1110      
selenium                  1105      
qt                        1099      
scala                     1090      
unit-testing              1037      
magento                   1036      
xcode                     1028      
google-chrome             1022      
sqlite                    1019      
powershell                1015      
rest                      1009      
image                     1007      
visual-studio-2010        992       
datetime                  991       
pdf                       984       
session                   971       
ubuntu                    950       
python-2.7                947       
windows                   944       
video                     920       
import                    905       
curl                      896       
database                  888       
listview                  886       
android-layout            885       
codeigniter               881       
shell                     869       
visual-studio             868       
nginx                     859       
facebook-graph-api        843       
paypal                    830       
amazon-s3                 825       
google-maps-api-3         820       
matplotlib                816       
opengl                    810       
jsp                       809       
google-app-engine         809       
highcharts                805       
d3.js                     775       
jpa                       773       
github                    762       
tomcat                    762       
svg                       755       
dictionary                747       
sorting                   738       
wcf                       737       
matrix                    731       
mod-rewrite               725       
cookies                   687       
validation                671       
perl                      653       
plot                      651       
jenkins                   649       
android-intent            648       
servlets                  646       
jsf                       632       
audio                     621       
encryption                619       
canvas                    614       
macros                    610       
caching                   609       
amazon-ec2                604       
svn                       604       
intellij-idea             600       
soap                      595       
redirect                  590       
heroku                    579       
ssh                       564       
express                   552       
iframe                    552       
xaml                      537       
checkbox                  522       
animation                 509       
gcc                       507       
vector                    491       
api                       486       
stored-procedures         477       
recursion                 475       
xpath                     475       
jquery-ui                 472       
jdbc                      469       
arraylist                 469       
authentication            464       
struct                    464       
twitter                   460       
bluetooth                 453       
iis                       452       
ember.js                  450       
serialization             447       
asynchronous              444       
pointers                  441       
pdo                       435       
grails                    432       
mysqli                    429       
tcp                       427       
awk                       424       
gridview                  420       
jquery-mobile             416       
google-analytics          411       
android-listview          410       
groovy                    401       
ffmpeg                    400       
generics                  399       
xslt                      397       
youtube                   397       
boost                     396       
lambda                    395       
tfs                       392       
proxy                     389       
cakephp                   388       
haskell                   387       
sed                       387       
utf-8                     385       
webview                   382       
templates                 379       
join                      370       
reporting-services        368       
dll                       365       
firefox                   359       
winforms                  357       
mvvm                      355       
enums                     353       
charts                    351       
oauth                     349       
sql-server-2008           344       
fonts                     336       
outlook                   328       
jar                       326       
datagridview              326       
backbone.js               325       
list                      324       
delphi                    322       
devise                    320       
pagination                317       
android-asynctask         315       
sharepoint                313       
logging                   312       
doctrine2                 310       
combobox                  310       
datatable                 309       
bitmap                    308       
solr                      304       
jsf-2                     301       
opengl-es                 300       
netbeans                  293       
knockout.js               293       
primefaces                292       
junit                     290       
flash                     289       
hash                      288       
activerecord              287       
internet-explorer         286       
ant                       281       
calendar                  280       
inheritance               277       
datepicker                273       
cuda                      273       
core-data                 269       
jboss                     268       
wsdl                      268       
networking                265       
ftp                       265       
asp.net-web-api           264       
unicode                   263       
vim                       257       
uiview                    256       
razor                     254       
random                    250       
monotouch                 246       
windows-phone-8           245       
crystal-reports           241       
ssis                      239       
extjs                     235       
printing                  224       
android-ndk               219       
merge                     218       
security                  218       
yii                       218       
post                      217       
actionscript-3            217       
transactions              214       
dns                       213       
flex                      213       
makefile                  213       
xsd                       212       
safari                    207       
lua                       206       
cron                      205       
rspec                     205       
memory-leaks              204       
ipad                      202       
encoding                  201       
timer                     200       
spring-security           199       
uiscrollview              198       
uiviewcontroller          197       
phpmyadmin                196       
drupal                    196       
datagrid                  195       
camera                    194       
multidimensional-array    193       
drupal-7                  189       
unix                      187       
autocomplete              186       
parsing                   183       
performance               182       
listbox                   179       
mono                      177       
sqlite3                   175       
tabs                      175       
debugging                 175       
msbuild                   174       
android-emulator          171       
memory                    170       
drop-down-menu            169       
3d                        166       
vbscript                  165       
gem                       164       
tree                      163       
jaxb                      162       
doctrine                  161       
notifications             158       
zend-framework            157       
assembly                  156       
clojure                   154       
garbage-collection        152       
stl                       151       
cmd                       150       
gps                       147       
wix                       147       
sharepoint-2010           147       
google-apps-script        146       
gwt                       146       
file-upload               146       
linux-kernel              146       
joomla                    145       
oop                       145       
version-control           145       
foreach                   141       
coffeescript              141       
uiwebview                 139       
user-interface            138       
java-ee                   136       
uibutton                  134       
oracle11g                 134       
google-chrome-extension   130       
dom                       128       
struts2                   128       
rss                       124       
telerik                   124       
lucene                    124       
rotation                  123       
graph                     122       
keyboard                  120       
parallel-processing       119       
nhibernate                119       
glassfish                 118       
cocoa                     118       
memory-management         115       
uiimage                   115       
uiimageview               115       
emacs                     113       
https                     112       
air                       109       
treeview                  109       
colors                    108       
jqgrid                    107       
cryptography              106       
optimization              106       
coldfusion                97        
mobile                    96        
dependency-injection      94        
mfc                       90        
django-models             86        
applet                    83        
url-rewriting             82        
nullpointerexception      80        
dojo                      77        
jvm                       76        
events                    73        
popup                     73        
vb6                       73        
permissions               71        
orm                       68        
widget                    68        
silverlight               67        
rubygems                  66        
user-controls             66        
linker                    65        
drag-and-drop             64        
windows-runtime           63        
plsql                     61        
concurrency               60        
hyperlink                 58        
namespaces                58        
table                     57        
tsql                      56        
login                     56        
constructor               55        
math                      51        
image-processing          51        
time                      51        
search                    50        
ms-access                 48        
winapi                    48        
fluent-nhibernate         48        
deployment                48        
data-binding              47        
class                     47        
delegates                 46        
annotations               44        
filter                    44        
nsstring                  44        
url                       43        
character-encoding        43        
plugins                   42        
stream                    40        
static                    40        
module                    39        
asp-classic               39        
cocos2d-iphone            37        
menu                      37        
xna                       36        
internet-explorer-8       35        
include                   35        
hover                     34        
loops                     34        
callback                  34        
casting                   32        
null                      32        
split                     31        
layout                    31        
extjs4                    31        
dialog                    30        
webforms                  30        
iis-7                     29        
python-3.x                28        
routing                   27        
webkit                    27        
reflection                25        
sql-server-2005           25        
passwords                 25        
testing                   24        
windows-8                 22        
cocoa-touch               22        
active-directory          22        
design-patterns           20        
windows-phone-7           20        
sql-server-2008-r2        19        
ruby-on-rails-3.2         19        
grid                      19        
navigation                18        
asp.net-mvc-3             17        
blackberry                16        
floating-point            15        
ios6                      15        
onclick                   15        
file                      14        
exception                 12        
get                       12        
actionscript              12        
data-structures           12        
service                   12        
ms-word                   11        
textbox                   11        
upload                    11        
http                      11        
function                  10        
interface                 10        
select                    10        
routes                    9         
scroll                    9         
resize                    9         
playframework             9         
graphics                  9         
count                     9         
iterator                  8         
visual-c++                8         
replace                   7         
scope                     7         
map                       7         
ado.net                   7         
eclipse-plugin            6         
group-by                  6         
variables                 6         
triggers                  6         
synchronization           6         
path                      5         
crash                     5         
binding                   5         
button                    4         
content-management-system 4         
for-loop                  4         
process                   4         
terminal                  4         
geolocation               3         
linq-to-sql               3         
localization              3         
django-templates          3         
build                     3         
android-widget            3         
binary                    2         
attributes                2         
compiler-errors           2         
database-design           2         
maps                      2         
mercurial                 2         
insert                    2         
web-config                2         
properties                2         
oracle10g                 1         
model                     1         
methods                   1         
sdk                       1         
resources                 1         
reference                 1         
qt4                       1         
styles                    1         
web-applications          1         
visual-studio-2008        1         
text                      1         
thread-safety             1         
xml-parsing               1         
input                     1         
internationalization      1         
exception-handling        1         
file-io                   1         
compilation               1         
compiler-construction     1         
console                   1         
collections               1         
django-forms              1         
ef-code-first             1         
download                  1         
design                    1         
background                1         
architecture              1
```

Here's a list of all tags suggested during the past 30 days that were under 6 months old when suggested OR where the tag no longer exists on the site today (+ number of times suggested):

```
tag suggested 
--- --------- 

(0 row(s) returned)
```

I don't see that this is a real problem.

Comment: Weird, swift* isn't on the list? Why is that?

Comment: No idea, @Braiam; that'd be a question for balpha. My uneducated guess would be that there's just not a strong enough correlation between any keywords usually found in swift questions and those tags; I wonder if they don't suffer from living in the shadow of [tag:objective-c].